# Nonhomogeneous Heat Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Solve the nonhomogeneous heat problem:

$u_t = ku_{xx} + sin(mx)$ for $-\infty < x < \infty$, where $u(x,0)=0$. In addition, $m>0$ is some constant.

Because the source function is $sin(mx)$, I know I can solve this problem by observing $u(x,t)=g(t)sin(mx)$. Then, I would have to find an ODE for $g$ and solve it. But I cannot figure out what $g$ is? My original apparoach to problem was:

$u_t = g'(t)sin(mx)$ by the Product Rule. Afterwards, I noticed in order for $u_t$ to be similar to the $u_t$ defined in the problem, $g'(t)=1$. Thus, $g(t)=t$, which gives $u(x,t)=tsin(mx)$. However, I believe there is a flaw to my logic because because when you take the derivative of my answer with respect to $x$ twice, then the result is not of the form $u_t - sin(mx)$.

Can someone explain how I can determine $g(t)$? Or if there is an alternative approach to finding $u(x,t)$ please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just had to develop your initial guess further. If you think that solution to equation is must be of form $u(x, t) = g(t) \sin mx$, plug it in heat equation. You'll get that $g^\prime(t) \sin mx = -m^2\cdot g(t) \sin mx + sin(mx)$. Since $\sin mx$ doesn't vanish everywhere, you can divide by it and obtain $g^\prime(t) = -m^2 g(t) + 1$. This is nonhomogeneous linear ODE which has solution $C\exp(-m^2 t) + \frac{1}{m^2}$. Constant $C$ can be find from $u(x, 0) = 0$.